# Calculating current fuel level with obd data

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption

My car does not provide the fuel level data to the obd.
this is the data the car do provide:
engine coolant temperature, engine load, ambient air temperature, engine rpm, intake manifold pressure, air intake temperature, speed, short term fuel, long term fuel, throttle position, timing advance, **wideband air fuel ratio**, **air fuel ratio**.

Is there any way to calculate the current fuel level with the given data?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In a word: no. You could *possibly* do it by calculating how much was left using how much fuel was getting used, but you'd have to reset it *everytime* you put gas in the tank and have to know (for any given vehicle) how much gas was in the tank. Realistically I think you need to dig deeper on what is provided. I'd bet there's a PID which will tell you how much gas is in the tank. My GM vehicle tells me an approximate range. I gather this is from knowing my gas mileage and how much fuel is in the tank. I'm pretty sure it's common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way accurately calculate fuel level if the ECU doesn't broadcast it.

As Paulster2 said you may be able to calculate fuel used over distance but it would be very very inaccurate.

One option would be to look at the wiring diagram of your vehicle and see how the fuel sensor is connected to the gauge, if it goes through a control module or MCU then you may be able to analyse the raw CAN bus data. If it is connected through a control module there might be a manufacture specific PID, you would have to work this out by connecting a high level diagnostic tool and looking at the live data while analysing the CAN bus messages.